# Problems with Contact Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have something similar to friends table. Its called `contacts`. It has:

- `user_id` is ID for user that's like owner of that contact,
- `contact_id` is ID for that user that's in friends with `user_id`;

There is the second table called `events`. It has:

- `user_id` is ID of user that's creator of that event.

I need to select events created by my friends. So if I have John and Anna in my contact list... I need to display events of them.

Here is solution:

```
SELECT `bio_community_events`.`id`, 
       `bio_community_events`.`begin_on`, 
       `bio_community_events`.`name`
  FROM `bio_community_events`
  JOIN `bio_contacts` ON (`bio_contacts`.`contact_id` = `bio_community_events`.`user_id`)
 WHERE `bio_contacts`.`user_id` = '33'
```

I.e., my ID is `33`.  It gives me events of my friends. And here comes the problem...

There are situations when I'm not the one who make contacts with my friend. Vice versa, Anna did it. This query would simply ignore that and don't display results for Anna.

Comment: Why are you relating to the creator of the event, rather than to the event record itself?

Comment: Like `SELECT ... FROM bio_contacts`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT `bio_community_events`.`id`, 
       `bio_community_events`.`begin_on`, 
       `bio_community_events`.`name`
  FROM `bio_community_events`
  JOIN `bio_contacts`
    ON (`bio_contacts`.`contact_id` = `bio_community_events`.`user_id`)
 WHERE `bio_contacts`.`user_id` = '33'

UNION ALL                                 --- or UNION if this gives you
                                          --- duplicate row
SELECT `bio_community_events`.`id`, 
       `bio_community_events`.`begin_on`, 
       `bio_community_events`.`name`
  FROM `bio_community_events`
  JOIN `bio_contacts` 
    ON (`bio_contacts`.`user_id` = `bio_community_events`.`user_id`)
 WHERE `bio_contacts`.`contact_id` = '33'
```

or like this:

```
SELECT `bio_community_events`.`id`, 
       `bio_community_events`.`begin_on`, 
       `bio_community_events`.`name`
  FROM `bio_community_events`
  JOIN 
    ( SELECT `bio_contacts`.`contact_id` AS id
        FROM `bio_contacts`
       WHERE `bio_contacts`.`user_id` = '33'
    UNION ALL                               
      SELECT `bio_contacts`.`user_id` AS id 
        FROM `bio_contacts`                                  
       WHERE `bio_contacts`.`contact_id` = '33'
    ) AS un
    ON ( un.id = `bio_community_events`.`user_id`)
```

---

To to set limit to all returned rows in example #1 use:

```
( SELECT ... )
UNION ALL
( SELECT ... )

ORDER BY ?        --- optional
LIMIT x ;
```

Using `ORDER BY` there can be quite costly in such a query. You can also have this (different) query which can use indexes:

```
( SELECT ... 
  ORDER BY ?
  LIMIT a
)
UNION ALL
( SELECT ...
  ORDER BY ?
  LIMIT b
)

LIMIT x ;         --- with or without this LIMIT
```

---

Another way to solve the original problem is using `EXISTS` :

```
SELECT `bio_community_events`.`id`, 
       `bio_community_events`.`begin_on`, 
       `bio_community_events`.`name`
  FROM `bio_community_events`
  WHERE EXISTS  
      ( SELECT *
          FROM `bio_contacts`
         WHERE `bio_contacts`.`user_id` = '33'
           AND `bio_contacts`.`contact_id` = `bio_community_events`.`user_id`
      )
     OR EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
          FROM `bio_contacts`
         WHERE `bio_contacts`.`contact_id` = '33'
           AND `bio_contacts`.`user_id` = `bio_community_events`.`user_id`
      )
```

or:

```
SELECT `bio_community_events`.`id`, 
       `bio_community_events`.`begin_on`, 
       `bio_community_events`.`name`
  FROM `bio_community_events`
  WHERE EXISTS  
      ( SELECT *
          FROM `bio_contacts`
         WHERE ( `bio_contacts`.`user_id` = '33'
             AND `bio_contacts`.`contact_id` = `bio_community_events`.`user_id` )
           OR  ( `bio_contacts`.`contact_id` = '33'
             AND `bio_contacts`.`user_id` = `bio_community_events`.`user_id` )
      )
```

---

If your plan is to find the most efficient query, try all that work correctly (using IN, using UNION, using EXISTS) - adding the `ORDER BY` you want off course - and checking their speed and execution plans.

I would at least have:

- in table `bio_community_events`

  - an index on `user_id`
  - an index on the field(s) used for `ORDER BY`

and

- in table `bio_contacts`, two compound indexes

  - on  `(contact_id, user_id)` and
  - on `(user_id, contact_id)`

And post another question if you can't make it run in less than X milliseconds (X decided by your boss :)

Comment: How to set limit to all returned rows in example #1?

Comment: Is there any *faster* way? My boss told me that this query isn't good, because when there will be like million entries... it gonna took a lot time to execute. Is that so?

Comment: Which version of the query? If you use an `ORDER BY` in the exterior query, yes, it will be slow with lot of rows. If you have `a` and `b` very small in the interior queries, then you can have ORDER BY in the exterior too, and still be quick.

Comment: If you have limits `a` and `b` set very high and indexes on the fields that are ordered it will be fast. Just optimize first and separately `(SELECT ... ORDER BY ? LIMIT a)` and `(SELECT ... ORDER BY ? LIMIT a)` and then try the `UNION ALL`, (the very last query, without an `ORDER BY` in the exterior).

Comment: Another comment. Even with millions of rows in the tables, how many events will that user (33) will be associated with? Hundreds? Thousands? That will affect the speed and the difficulty of optimizing the subqueries.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, begin_on, name 
FROM bio_community_events 
WHERE user_id IN ( SELECT user_id FROM bio_contacts WHERE contact_id = '33')
OR user_id IN ( SELECT contact_id FROM bio_contacts WHERE user_id = '33')
```

Comment: This gives me my events as well.

Comment: Do you want only your friends events? If so I have edited my example

Comment: Yes, i want only events of my friends. Not myself. Not anyone else. You edited example acts very strange. It returns the same entry 12 times!

Comment: TRy again. I am on my mobile now so have no way to test any SQL.

Comment: This query returns all my events and events from guy that have `bio_contacts`.`contact_id` = 33. Nothing is returned from guys that have `bio_contacts`.`user_id` = 33.

Comment: This edit works! Anyway, I would love to do the same effect with only joins and without inner select. Is it possible?

Comment: No sorry, undoable without nested queries imo. Any particular reason for that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586079/whether-inner-queries-are-okay/6586355#6586355

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the user ids of your friends as well:

```
SELECT `bio_community_events`.`id`, `bio_community_events`.`begin_on`, `bio_community_events`.`name`
FROM `bio_community_events`
JOIN `bio_contacts`
    ON (`bio_contacts`.`contact_id` = `bio_community_events`.`user_id`)
WHERE `bio_contacts`.`user_id` = '33'
OR `bio_contacts`.`user_id` IN (SELECT `contact_id` FROM `contacts` WHERE `user_id` = 33)
```

Comment: [Err] 1052 - Column 'user_id' in where clause is ambiguous.

Comment: I fixed that error. Wrong table name in 2nd select. Anyway, this query gives me the same results as before.

Comment: Well, you said your table was named "contacts", or is it bio_contacts?

Comment: Yes, my bad. Anyway, that doesn't change the fact... query returns the same results as my query (in question). Any ideas why?